# How to trigger an event when user slides carousel only in the Right direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On my bootstrap carousel, I trigger today an [event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events) based on slide.bs.carousel, but I would like to restrict it to only sliding to the right direction.

**Current code (working)**

```
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
      alert('slided a slide');      
    });
```

**My attempt at only triggering it when user slide to the right (not working):**

```
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', {direction: 'right'}, function(e) {
      alert('slide a slide in the right direction');      
    });
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event has an direction property (but in my case the direction are inversed 'right when I click on left'), can't you just make a condition on it like this ?

```
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
   if ('right' == e.direction) {
       alert('slided a slide');      
   }      
});
```

Comment: worked perfectly thanks, indeed directions are opposite, I had to formally use 'left' in my case

Answer (score 0):

Can use preventDefault to restrict it

```
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
  if(event.direction === 'left'){
    event.preventDefault()
  } 
})
```